# android floating view bubble

Tags: android, service

I am building an app for android using android studio, and whenever I run the app directly on my phone, it crashes when I start a `FloatingViewService` on button click. I must run it on my phone because I have no virtualization on my laptop.

And yes, I did add the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

And I also declared FloatingViewService in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<service android:name=".FloatingViewService" />
```

But still no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my entire code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.icetea09.demofloatingview.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_show_floating_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Show Floating View"/>
```

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FloatingViewService extends Service {

private WindowManager mWindowManager;
private ImageView mImgFloatingView;
private boolean mIsFloatingViewAttached = false;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    //Not use this method
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(!mIsFloatingViewAttached){
        mWindowManager.addView(mImgFloatingView, mImgFloatingView.getLayoutParams());
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    mImgFloatingView = new ImageView(this);
    mImgFloatingView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

    mWindowManager.addView(mImgFloatingView, params);

    mIsFloatingViewAttached = true;

    mImgFloatingView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float initialTouchX;
        private float initialTouchY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mImgFloatingView, params);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public void removeView() {
    if (mImgFloatingView != null){
        mWindowManager.removeView(mImgFloatingView);
        mIsFloatingViewAttached = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    super.onDestroy();
    removeView();
}
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button mBtnShowView;
private boolean mIsFloatingViewShow; //Flag variable used to identify if the Floating View is visible or not

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mBtnShowView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_show_floating_view);
    mBtnShowView.setOnClickListener(this);
    mIsFloatingViewShow = false;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn_show_floating_view:
            if(mIsFloatingViewShow){
                hideFloatingView();
                mIsFloatingViewShow = false;
                mBtnShowView.setText(R.string.show_floating_view);
            }
            else{
                showFloatingView();
                mIsFloatingViewShow = true;
                mBtnShowView.setText(R.string.hide_floating_view);
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void showFloatingView() {
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FloatingViewService.class));
}

private void hideFloatingView() {
    stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FloatingViewService.class));
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from the "Android Monitor" tab in Android Studio?

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/gpwq5k97b/

Comment: the actual problem is that I downaod that app from github and than prescribe the code(all clases, manifest,resourses all) and my app crashes when I clik on the button Show floating view. WHY is that so I dont understand :(

Comment: Posting the actual stack trace instead of an image would be better, I can't read the full thing like this... I see something "Permission denied..." but it get's cut off

Comment: 11-26 18:09:39.190 30884-30884/com.example.denis.mylastapp I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-26 18:09:39.190 30884-30884/com.example.denis.mylastapp I/art: VMHOOK: rlim_cur : 0 pid:30884
11-26 18:09:39.294 30884-30884/com.example.denis.mylastapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.denis.mylastapp-1/lib/arm64
11-26 18:09:39.300 30884-30884/com.example.denis.mylastapp I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.denis.mylastapp, real application class is null.
11-26 18:09:39.379 30884-30884/

Comment: 11-26 18:09:39.438 30884-30884/com.example.denis.mylastapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process:

Comment: com.example.denis.mylastapp, PID: 30884
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.denis.mylastapp.FloatingViewService: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@911b14b -- permission denied for this window type
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3010)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:150)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)

Comment: Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@911b14b -- permission denied for this window type
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:620)
                                                                                 at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310)

Comment: at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                                 at com.example.denis.mylastapp.FloatingViewService.onCreate(FloatingViewService.java:52)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2992)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:150)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845) 
                                                                                 at

Comment: I solved the problem,the system alert  permission was  not automatically granted because app was sideloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST
```

instead

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
```